# Object property called with dot notation showing console.log 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods

fairly new to Javascript.

Can I please get an explanation why object property of displayMyList when accessed with dot notation logs as ‘undefined’ but when put in a function it works fine. Why does it show undefined with just the console log? Why doesn't it get displayed and why does it need a function to do so.

Here’s the code.

```
var toDoList = {
// Holding the List 
myList: ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4', 'List5'],
// Displaying the List
displayMyList: console.log(this.myList)
}
```

This will display it as ‘undefined’ when I try to access the object property displayMyList with dot notation. However when a method is used it displays the list fine. I am wondering why is that?

```
 var toDoList = {
    // Holding the List 
    myList: ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4', 'List5'],
    // Displaying the List
    displayMyList: function(){
  console.log(this.myList)
}
    }
```

Comment: Just see what "this" evaluates to - `console.log(this)`.  That'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

---

```
var toDoList = {
  // Holding the List 
  myList: ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4', 'List5'],
  // Displaying the List
  displayMyList: console.log(this.myList)
}
```

There are a couple problems here with your first example above.

- First, you are setting a property in toDoList called `displayMyList` to the RETURN VALUE of `console.log(this.myList)`. console.log() does not return any value (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) so the value being assigned to `displayMyList` will always be `undefined`.
- And second, it will evaluate this and see what it returns (at this time `this` refers to the global `this` unless it has otherwise been set to another context. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis. So you'll be looking at the property `myList` of globalThis (or otherwise what `this` is bound to in that context).

```
var toDoList = {
  // Holding the List 
  myList: ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4', 'List5'],
  // Displaying the List
  displayMyList: function() {
    console.log(this.myList)
  }
};
```

This fixes those, you are:

- Assigning displayMyList to be a FUNCTION that you will run later in the context of `toDoList` being `this`.

Note how the use of `function` keyword here rebinds `this` to the containing object.

- If you defined the function without `function` keyword, e.g. `displayMyList: () => console.log(this.myList),` it would also not work because arrow functions do not rebind `this`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
- Similarly, even if you used the `function` keyword. If you called the function in a different way, it would also not work. Examples below:

```
// Won't work
const x = toDoList.displayMyList;
x();

// Won't work
toDoList.displayMyList.call(globalThis);

// Won't work
toDoList.displayMyList.apply({});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an [object method](https://javascript.info/object-methods) to log your list

```js
var toDoList = {
  // Holding the List 
  myList: ['List1', 'List2', 'List3', 'List4', 'List5'],
  // Displaying the List
  displayMyList() { console.log(this.myList) },
}


toDoList.displayMyList()
```